# Javascript REST API Error with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, rest, flask

I have deployed a flask framework on the pythonanywhere website, with the following code, whose third method handles rest requests:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Sachin Flask!'
@app.route('/getval')
def getter():
    return '3'
@app.route('/get', methods=['GET'])
def get_task():
    return jsonify({"tasks": "tas",})
```

Website: https://sachk480.pythonanywhere.com/

I wrote a simple javascript getter which grabs the data from the /get url and displays it to the console, but I keep receiving this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

This error points to the JSON data and its format, and I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Javascript getter: https://jsfiddle.net/sachinkonan480/04bx0sye/5/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is in your dictionary there's a comma after the last value, it's not valid json

Comment: I fixed that in the flask code just now, but am facing the same error on the javascript end

Comment: That just means your javascript code is not making a valid json?

Comment: Sure but I think that happens in the background Ajax function --where I can't figure out the cause of the error.

Comment: When changing the dataType from 'jsonp' to 'json' this error pops up: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You are missing CORS on flask

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnywhere dev here, when I visit your site I see an error:

https://sachk480.pythonanywhere.com/get

My guess is that your app is actually returning a 500 error, which is not valid json, so that's why your javascript can't parse it.

have a look at your error log on pythonanywhere?  there's a few tips on debugging common problems here: http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError

Comment: Yeah since I posted the question I changed the flask backend. Now the url requires a int key argument so this would work: https://sachk480.pythonanywhere.com/get/0.

Comment: and are you still seeing problems?  email support@pythonanywhere.com, we'll try and help :)

Comment: Nope just by specifying a cors decorator, my problems have been eliminated. But thanks though!